# How to reduce the bundle size in next JS?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, next.js, i18next

I can able to see the size is 0B but the first load JS file size is more than **300KB**. Even 404-page first load JS **300KB** It reduces the initial load performance as well. Is it require to add our own webpack configuration in the next js config?. I've attached the reference image. Please help me out here.

size for each file after build

[image]

I've tried with webpackBundleAnalyzer as well. For _app.js as per the build report in terminal it's showing 0B and 389KB on First Load JS server.html. Attached that image as well.

_app.js bundle Analyzer

[image]

Comment: Try to use withBundleAnalyzer plugin to watch what's bundled?